# SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed error when downloading VS Code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just formatted my computer and installed VS Code, but when I went to download some extension, an error appeared and asked to check the "log", and then an error appeared in the console.

[image of the error that appears in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CryJ9.png)

I tried searching the program files but found nothing.

> 2023-02-08 19:01:39.542 [error] SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed:
> Signature: SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed
> at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
> at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)

Comment: Copy and paste the error into the question and let us know more about what you're trying to run when it fails

Comment: Related Github Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173250

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround. There is an issue raised but long inactive [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113891)

Try this, this worked for me after all the other struggle with this bug.

> "Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" **--ignore-certificate-errors**

The security part of this is that, your trust store or at least the one VS code is using is not able to verify the authenticity. So be mindful of the risk involved.

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain what the security ramifications of using this command and that flag are?

Comment: unworkable suggestion provided by different people since this bug appeared (MS has changed their way to verify  downloads and in some cases VS Code install no needed certificates) 
according to github discussion the fixing of this issue was deleted from even April revision
>  sandy081 removed this from the April 2023 milestone Mar 21, 2023
let's hope they fix it someday

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.77 has no more that issue.
You can close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. VS Code 1.77 includes a "patch" (more like a workaround I think) for this, and the maintainers are working on fixing the underlying issues in the meantime. See [the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77#_extension-installation-not-blocked-by-signature-verification-failures), which state:

> **Extension installation not blocked by signature verification failures**
>
> Extension signature verification is incorrectly reporting errors for a small number of valid extensions and preventing them from being installed. These failures are caused by bugs in the VS Marketplace and VS Code and we are actively working on fixes. In order to unblock extension use, VS Code will install extensions even if signing verification fails. We will reenable signature verification checking once [VS Marketplace issue #619](https://github.com/microsoft/vsmarketplace/issues/619) is fixed, most likely in our next Stable release.

See also this related issue ticket: [update/install extensions got the `SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed` error
#173250](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173250).