# SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed (Failed to Install Extension)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I've been having this problem for a **while**, does anyone have a solution?

It's not a DNS error, Ipv6 or something like that, and the command to turn off certified check doesn't work anymore.

I'm literally trying to download official Microsoft Plugins and I get a certificate error
Like:

```
2023-03-22 17:08:35.669 [error] SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed: Error: SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed,SignatureIntegrityCheckFailed
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:89716
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

Really need some workable solution.

I've tried things related to WiFi and commands in the Program but nothing worked, not that they've mentioned so far.
It should just install normally and work

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75393695/11107541 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173250 (please provide additional debugging info here and to that GitHub issue to help us and them find the cause(s) of this error)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was resolved by running vscode as an administrator, as the standard user did not have sufficient permissions to read the file that indicates the path of the error.